# How do I use String Categories as a Feature in a Tensor? (if possible in tensorflow js)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have the following categories in a dataset, where Region and Years will be used to predict the Salary

```
Regions: ['Europe', 'North America', 'South America', 'Asia', 'Africa'] 

Data sample:
{region: 'Asia', years: 5, salary: 1000}
{region: 'Asia', years: 3, salary: 700}
{region: 'Asia', years: 1, salary: 300}
{region: 'Europe', years: 5, salary: 3000}
```

I would like to use region and years as Xs and salary as Ys.

I've tried to convert regions to tf.oneHot, but can't figure out how to use them together with "years" as oneHot return is another tensor.

```
indices = tf.tensor1d([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'int32');
oneHot = tf.oneHot(indices, 5);
oneHot result -> [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],...]


xs = tf.tensor2d([[?, 5], [?, 3], [?, 1], [?, 5]]); //[region, years]
ys = tf.tensor1d([1000, 700, 300, 3000]); //[salary]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.concat` can be used

```
indices = tf.tensor1d([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'int32');
const oneHot = tf.oneHot(indices, 5);

const xs_add = tf.tensor([5, 3, 1, 5, 4]).reshape([5, 1])

xs = tf.concat([oneHot, xs_add], 1)
xs.print()
```